# Complejidad Algorítmica

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, complejidad

¿Qué complejidad algorítmica tiene este código?

```
n*=n
for(let i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
   //algo
}
```

En especifico tengo la duda si es de O(n) o O(n<sup>2</sup>). He buscado en internet y he encontrado ambas respuestas en foros y en blogs, en cambio no he podido encontrar un ejemplo similar en documentación bibliográfica.

Lo más cercano que he encontrado es en el libro *Introducción a los algoritmos* de Thomas H. Cormen, donde hay un ejemplo que el for llega hasta √n y donde da que su complejidad es de O(√n)

Si uno grafica el número de iteraciones de un for que va hasta 2*n se dará cuenta que es una función lineal solo que la pendiente cambia, lo cual si se puede decir que es lineal porque la propia definición de Big-O incluye una constante multiplicada por g(x) para esos casos pero si el número de iteraciones crece de manera cuadrática ya ahí si no podríamos decir que es lineal. Ahí está mi gran duda

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! pues... eso es una iteracion.. no hay mucha complejidad ahi... creo que esta no es tu pregunta en si.. que es lo que queres preguntar realmente?? porque esto, esta hasta en google...

Comment: @gbianchi el algoritmo tiene complejidad lineal O(n), no entiendo pq cerraste la pregunta, me parece válida y respondíble, la complejidad algorítmica es toda una ciencia dentro de las ciencias de la computación, además el op no busca ni libros ni recomendaciones

Comment: Stackoverflow fue quien la cerró, por qué es lineal? La primera linea no afecta a la n del ciclo for? O sea mi duda es si n=n*n afecta a la n del for haciendonlo ir hasta n^2

Comment: @Japv mira el historial.antes de la edicion pedia libros sobre el tema. Aunque la complejidad algoritmica es un tema en si, y valido, es valido si hay un intento no? un for, no tiene complejidad algoritmica... no? o es siempre igual.. no?

Comment: La primera línea tiene un orden constante, y no afecta al ciclo

Comment: @Japv si quieres te la reabro.. pero mas que una respuesta, vas a tener que darrle una explicacion de manual para que te la llegue a aceptar...

Comment: @gbianchi yo creo que puede reabrirse, no me parece que merezca ser cerrada

Comment: A ver solo quiero saber el porqué, hay quien dice que es n^2 y otros lineal, en que libro puedo encontrar este ejemplo, con eso me conformo, gracias

Comment: @Japv ves.. esta buscando un libro, no una respuesta...

Comment: @Lenar que quien te dijo que es n^2 te explique porque, porque esta mal. Hay montones de libros, sitios e inclusive google que pueden ayudarte a entender la complejidad de un algortimo.. aca basicamente, la complejidad depende de la cantidad de vueltas que le des a la lista.. y la cantidad, es siempre igual.. es n.. sin importa que hiciste con n antes...

Comment: @lenar solo hay un ciclo for? No hay ciclos anidados?

Comment: No, solo ese ciclo

Comment: @Japv OP ni leyo el recorrido (por mas que se lo pedi en el primer comentario).. solo quiere la respuesta para su ejercicio... ;)

Comment: Editas la pregunta, y nos cuentas que fue lo que averiguaste sobre este tema, porque pensas que tiene una complejidad determinada, y que te hace decir que llegaste a esa complejidad? asi vamos a poder corregirte.. decir que te dijeron, no nos sirve. Si no, necesitas una clase completa de complejidad. Y no, no damos recomendaciones de nada aca...

Comment: Ya olvidenlo, no es para un ejercicio, solo quería saber porque me he encontrado con esos dos criterios como el de que un for que llega hasta la raiz de n que algunos dicen que es O(n) y otros O(√n)

Comment: @Lenar es lineal, la multiplicación previa tiene un costo despreciable, no se tie en cuenta, esa es la respuesta

Comment: Es lineal, n no está dentro de un ciclo, no hay ciclos anidados

Comment: Y de n estar dentro de un ciclo tampoco fueraO(n^2), fuera exponencial e intratable

Comment: @Lenar no puedes pedir libros, pero si una prueba bibliográfica que compruebe educativamente cual de las dos respuesta es la correcta. si es que existe. y según los comentarios parece que has investigado un poco pero eso no se ve en tu redaccion/post agradeceríamos que antes de continuar hagas el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea de como funciona el sitio y la forma correcta de plantear las preguntas. cualquier ayuda no dudes en preguntar, saludos ️

Answer (score 1):

De los comentarios asumo que estamos hablando solo de la *complejidad temporal* y dado que para este caso hablar de la *complejidad espacial* tiene poco sentido, atenderé solo a lo primero.

Si tienes una función:

```js
function calcular(n) {
  n*=n
  for(let i=0; i<=n; i++){
    algo();
  }
}
```

Y digamos que calcular `algo()` demora siempre 1 segundo, con:

| *n* | Tiempo (s) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 16 |

Como se puede ver el tiempo necesario (o la cantidad de operaciones), aumenta de forma cuadrática en relación a la entrada *n*, por tanto esa función es de

##### *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>)

---

La complejidad no viene dada por la cantidad de `for` que tenga un algoritmo, si no que por la variación de la cantidad de operaciones
que realiza en relación a la entrada ***n***

La misma función se podría escribir como

```
function calcular(n) {
  for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(let j=0;j<n;j++){
      algo();
    }
  }
  algo();
}
```

Y ahí estarían los 2 `for`, pero esa reescritura con cambia la complejidad, la función `algo()` con igual entrada ***n*** se ejecuta la misma cantidad de veces en ambos casos ¿por qué deberían tener complejidades algorítmicas distintas? No tendría lógica alguna.

Y lo mismo aplica en el caso contrario, digamos que tenemos esta función

```
function calcular(n) {
  for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
    algo();
  }
}
```

Es evidente que es de **O**(**n**), y si yo la reescribo de esta manera:

```
function calcular(n) {
  let n1 = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));
  let n2 = n-n1;
  for(let i=0; i <n1; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<n2; j++){
      algo();
    }
  }
}
```

Sigue siendo de **O**(**n**) aunque tenga 2 `for`

Comment: **Los comentarios han sido [movidos al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151152/discussion-on-answer-by-yussef-complejidad-algoritmica); por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí.** Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los [propósitos de los comentarios](/help/privileges/comment). Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una [respuesta](/help/how-to-answer), en [meta], o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Comment: @Yussef ya te di mi +1, revisé los enlaces que dejaste en el chat, releí tú respuesta y busque información, analice con más detalle y profundidad y saque conclusiones y finalmente asumo que tu explicación es correcta, felicidades y disculpa cualquier molestia ocasionada, fue un buen debate

Comment: @Yussef puede agregar aqui los link por favor es importante incluir documentacion en las respuesta para sustentar y evitar estas diferencias, saludos.

Comment: @Yussef gracias por editar, es que estaba ocupado